# give weight on some rows based on columns

Tags: python, pandas, select, dataframe, rows

This is my dataframe:

```
id   Year   Month   Day     Instant     Temperature     DayType     DayValidity     LoadNette   
192     2008    1   5   0   8.03    6   1   53039.77133     
193     2008    2   5   1   8.07    6   1   52200.71569     
194     2008    3   5   2   8.10    6   1   51681.17260     
195     2008    4   5   3   8.07    6   1   51907.94746     
196     2008    5   5   4   8.03    6   1   50848.16566
```

and i want to duplicate 5 times my dataframe but by giving wieghts for some rows based on Month like this for example the rows where month is 4 it will duplicate just 3 times and month 4 just 2 times likes this with python:

```
id   Year   Month   Day     Instant     Temperature     DayType     DayValidity     LoadNette   
192     2008    1   5   0   8.03    6   1   53039.77133     
193     2008    2   5   1   8.07    6   1   52200.71569     
194     2008    3   5   2   8.10    6   1   51681.17260     
195     2008    4   5   3   8.07    6   1   51907.94746     
196     2008    5   5   4   8.03    6   1   50848.16566
192     2008    1   5   0   8.03    6   1   53039.77133     
193     2008    2   5   1   8.07    6   1   52200.71569     
194     2008    3   5   2   8.10    6   1   51681.17260     
195     2008    4   5   3   8.07    6   1   51907.94746     
196     2008    5   5   4   8.03    6   1   50848.16566
192     2008    1   5   0   8.03    6   1   53039.77133     
193     2008    2   5   1   8.07    6   1   52200.71569     
194     2008    3   5   2   8.10    6   1   51681.17260     
195     2008    4   5   3   8.07    6   1   51907.94746     
196     2008    5   5   4   8.03    6   1   50848.16566
192     2008    1   5   0   8.03    6   1   53039.77133     
193     2008    2   5   1   8.07    6   1   52200.71569     
194     2008    3   5   2   8.10    6   1   51681.17260     
195     2008    4   5   3   8.07    6   1   51907.94746     
192     2008    1   5   0   8.03    6   1   53039.77133     
193     2008    2   5   1   8.07    6   1   52200.71569     
194     2008    3   5   2   8.10    6   1   51681.17260
```

there are any way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dict` for number of repeating with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and dict comprehension:

```
d = {1:5, 2:2, 3:1, 4:3, 5:3}
l = df['Month'].map(d)
df = pd.DataFrame({col: np.repeat(df[col], l) for col in df.columns}, columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
print (df)
    id  Year  Month  Day  Instant  Temperature  DayType  DayValidity  \
0  192  2008      1    5        0         8.03        6            1   
0  192  2008      1    5        0         8.03        6            1   
0  192  2008      1    5        0         8.03        6            1   
0  192  2008      1    5        0         8.03        6            1   
0  192  2008      1    5        0         8.03        6            1   
1  193  2008      2    5        1         8.07        6            1   
1  193  2008      2    5        1         8.07        6            1   
2  194  2008      3    5        2         8.10        6            1   
3  195  2008      4    5        3         8.07        6            1   
3  195  2008      4    5        3         8.07        6            1   
3  195  2008      4    5        3         8.07        6            1   
4  196  2008      5    5        4         8.03        6            1   
4  196  2008      5    5        4         8.03        6            1   
4  196  2008      5    5        4         8.03        6            1   

     LoadNette  
0  53039.77133  
0  53039.77133  
0  53039.77133  
0  53039.77133  
0  53039.77133  
1  52200.71569  
1  52200.71569  
2  51681.17260  
3  51907.94746  
3  51907.94746  
3  51907.94746  
4  50848.16566  
4  50848.16566  
4  50848.16566
```

Another solution if need repeat all rows 5 times with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 5, ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
print (df)
     id  Year  Month  Day  Instant  Temperature  DayType  DayValidity  \
0   192  2008      1    5        0         8.03        6            1   
1   193  2008      2    5        1         8.07        6            1   
2   194  2008      3    5        2         8.10        6            1   
3   195  2008      4    5        3         8.07        6            1   
4   196  2008      5    5        4         8.03        6            1   
5   192  2008      1    5        0         8.03        6            1   
6   193  2008      2    5        1         8.07        6            1   
7   194  2008      3    5        2         8.10        6            1   
8   195  2008      4    5        3         8.07        6            1   
9   196  2008      5    5        4         8.03        6            1   
10  192  2008      1    5        0         8.03        6            1   
11  193  2008      2    5        1         8.07        6            1   
12  194  2008      3    5        2         8.10        6            1   
13  195  2008      4    5        3         8.07        6            1   
14  196  2008      5    5        4         8.03        6            1   
15  192  2008      1    5        0         8.03        6            1   
16  193  2008      2    5        1         8.07        6            1   
17  194  2008      3    5        2         8.10        6            1   
18  195  2008      4    5        3         8.07        6            1   
19  196  2008      5    5        4         8.03        6            1   
20  192  2008      1    5        0         8.03        6            1   
21  193  2008      2    5        1         8.07        6            1   
22  194  2008      3    5        2         8.10        6            1   
23  195  2008      4    5        3         8.07        6            1   
24  196  2008      5    5        4         8.03        6            1   

      LoadNette  
0   53039.77133  
1   52200.71569  
2   51681.17260  
3   51907.94746  
4   50848.16566  
5   53039.77133  
6   52200.71569  
7   51681.17260  
8   51907.94746  
9   50848.16566  
10  53039.77133  
11  52200.71569  
12  51681.17260  
13  51907.94746  
14  50848.16566  
15  53039.77133  
16  52200.71569  
17  51681.17260  
18  51907.94746  
19  50848.16566  
20  53039.77133  
21  52200.71569  
22  51681.17260  
23  51907.94746  
24  50848.16566
```

Comment: thank you but i want keep the same from of the data frame above (on the question) @jezreal

Comment: Do you think sorting?

Comment: I think you need add `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` and 
`df = df.reindex_axis(df.groupby(['id','Month']).cumcount().sort_values().index, axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)` if need same order as in sample.

Comment: No no sorting but duplicate all the data  frame no duplicate row by row

Comment: Then I dont understand - do you need duplicate all rows by column `Month`? Or need `pd.DataFrame({col: np.repeat(df[col], 5) for col in df.columns}, columns=df.columns)` ?  for duplicate all rows 5 times?

Comment: I add another solution if need repeat same way all data.

Comment: I check your desired output again and I think you need first solution, only valueas are sorted different. So need [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44670180/give-weight-on-some-rows-based-on-columns#comment76326705_44670546)

Comment: because the real values are:  d = {1:38880, 2:40800, 3:42000,4:27648, 5:13680,6:65664, 7:34560,9:36000, 10:42000,11:36000, 12:28800}
l = data['Month'].map(d)
#data = data.set_index([range(0,79488) ])
df = pd.DataFrame({col: np.repeat(data[col], l) for col in data.columns}, columns=data.columns)

Comment: Hmmm, so do you need repeating `1` `38880` times? `2` `40800` times, ...? Then output dataframe is realy huge and need much RAM for data processing. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147243/discussion-between-amal-kostali-targhi-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

used [`pandas.sample` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) with weights. the syntax:

```
#vec = <vector of rows weights>
df.sample(weights = vec)
```